# An icon set to extend Lions default icins,

Tags: macos, icon

Does anyone know of an icon set that he's the same blue icons as are standard in Lion, yet with extended meaning?

E.g. a folder with a pacman figure (to denote a games folder) on front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a pre-built set out there for you, but there's a nifty app on the Mac App Store called "[Folders Factory](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/folders-factory/id442153412?mt=12)" that makes it very easy to make customized folders.  Just drop in your pacman image and it'll create a folder and allow you to tweak settings, placement, colors, etc.

Comment: Oh, AWESOME! I always do extend the basic folders in certain directories, and could totally use that to unify the look.

Answer (score 0):

You could check 
http://interfacelift.com/icons/downloads/date/any/

for icons and you can always open an icon in preview hit cmd + a and then cmd +c then go to the folder you want to change, hit get info and in the top right corner click the folder icon and hit cmd +v for paste